# How to install ZfcBase (Zend Framework 2) without Git?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

I apologize if this is a trivial question.

The installation guide for [ZfcBase](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase) only provides this much info;

> "Simply clone this project into your ./vendor/ directory and enable it
>   in your ./config/application.config.php file."

I don't have git on my shared hosting solution, but I am using composer.

Could anyone give me a generic way in which I can install Zfc modules without git? (I'm new to Zend)

Edit: I'm guessing I can wget the zip to my /vendor folder and unzip it there? But this wouldn't be good, as I don't want to manually update it if a new version comes in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using composer, then add `"zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master"` to the `require` section of your composer.json. so that it looks something like:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-base": "dev-master"
}
```

Now you run:

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar update
```

On the command line.

Comment: The thing is I don't have git on my server (shared hosting) and composer gives me this;

"[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone http://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase.git, git was not found, check that it is instal
  led and in your PATH env."

I'm guessing I should urgently switch to a server with git.

Comment: Ah! Sorry. Which VCS are you using?

Comment: I have svn installed. But I'm not sure if it's compatible with what I'm trying to do. I'm going to accept your answer for now because I'm going to move to a server with git, but if you have an idea of how to do it without git, it would be nice.

Comment: Without git, you can't use composer to install ZfcBase. The way I would do it is to create a separate repository for ZfcBase within my svn system and then sync that to the official github one periodically. I would then use svn:externals to bring ZfcBase into my ZF2 project.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing shared hosting you should first consider developing on your own local computer.

Then, once you're satisfied, zip it all up and transfer it all to your server.

Developing ON the shared server is not a good idea because, as you can see, you won't have all the tools necessary to develop.

If 'zipping' it up all the time is difficult or tedious you can use a build tool for that. [Phing](http://www.phing.info/) or [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) will do.

If you're making small changes I don't see TOO much of a problem doing it on the shared server; but even then, it's still better to do it on your local machine so you can take advantage of an IDE, version control, quicker network, better tool set and probably some other things.